# How to fix "System.Exception: Component initialization failed" when using Windows.Media.Ocr with HEIF and WebP files in C# .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, ocr

I have C# .NET Framework application, that performs OCR using `Windows.Media.Ocr` API (referencing `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` package). I'm using code similar to [here](https://www.lostindetails.com/articles/using-windows-built-in-ocr-from-csharp):

```
var engine = OcrEngine.TryCreateFromLanguage(new Windows.Globalization.Language("en-US"));
string filePath = TestData.GetFilePath("image.png");
var file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
var softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
var ocrResult = await engine.RecognizeAsync(softwareBitmap);
Console.WriteLine(ocrResult.Text);
```

with png/jpg all works fine. however, when I try with .heif/.webp files, I get exception of: `System.Exception: The component initialization has failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F8B)`.

Looking at the definition of `BitmapDecoder` class, it looks like that all those file types should be supported (In class definition I can see DecoderId defined for each of those file types, such as `HeifDecoderId`/`WebpDecoderId`).

The [formal documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder?view=winrt-22621) doesn't mention those types as supported. but on the other hand they have DecoderId in class definition.

Any idea if possible to make those file types work?

Comment: Is the problem coming from the BitmapDecoder or the OcrEngine? The title of the question suggets that the problem is with the OcrEngine, but the description seems to suggest that the problem occurs even before you call RecognizeAsync.

Comment: The exception is coming from BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync. my application runs in system account. I now noticed that if I run the application in user account, the issue doesn't happen - heif and webp work fine.
So to summarize:
User account - work fine for all file types.
System account - jpg, png work fine. heif and webp -> exception above.

Comment: I now compared procmon for webp for user account vs system account.
System account: application tries to find MSWebp.dll under System32 folder and fails.
User account: application finds MSWebp.dll successfully under 
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WebpImageExtension_1.1.522.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\x64\MSWebp_store.dll

Comment: Oh, yeah, running as SYSTEM limits you to native format support. But trying to decode images as SYSTEM is incredibly dangerous. You are one malicious JPG away from being pwned.